# How to add a new Highchart dynamically using Highchartsng

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

So what I'm trying to do is when a user clicks a button I want to add a new highchart element to the page. Currently I see that my container for the chart shows up but the chart does not.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
//This config works when I statically load a graph
$scope.someConfig ={ options: {chart:{type:'pie'}}, title :{text: 'Test'}, series:[{data: [1,2,3,4]}]} 

angular.element($('myElement')).append{
"<div class='myContainerClass'>"+
  "<highchart config='config' style='height: 100%; width: 100%'>"+"<\highchart>"+
"</div>"
);
```

I'm still pretty new at this so I'm wondering what is I'm doing wrong

Any advice would be awesome!

Thank you~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `compile` that DOM using `$compile` API before appending it to the desired element. `$compile` service will make the binding working on that DOM with the scope specified in the brackets like `($scope)`.

**Code**

```
var compiledDOM = $compile("<div class='myContainerClass'>"+
  "<highchart config='config' style='height: 100%; width: 100%'>"+"<\highchart>"+
"</div>")($scope)
angular.element($('myElement')).append(compiledDOM)
```

Rather than appending DOM you could also think of `ng-repeat` directive which will dynamically renders the DOM based on the array provided to it. Basically it renders that html until that array length is reached.

So here in your case you could fill `charts` object which is basically an array. When users add new `chart` push one object to `charts` object which will `config` part like `charts.push({config: configObject})`

```
<div ng-repeat="chart in charts" class='myContainerClass'>"+
      <highchart config='chart.config' style='height: 100%; width: 100%'><\highchart>
</div>
```

Toggle flag `showHighChart` to showing & hiding `highcharts` DOM.

Comment: Thanks! The $compile did help solve part of the issue. I see the highchart elements showing up now in the inspector but it is all still blank. But atleast it is progress! As for the ng-if, I don't think that would help me here as I could be making for than1 highchart based on what the user chooses.

Comment: @werty0u ok then continue with the first part..now whats the issue?

Comment: Nothing is showing up still. I think although my config is valid theres some other disconnect between highchart and my config

Comment: @werty0u could you try my edit..for dynamic behaviour you could try that `ng-repeat` part

Comment: @werty0u Glad to help you..Thanks :)